# Правильная работа с шаблонами

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите как правильно.
Есть простой вывод, допустим карточек товаров.

Шаблон template.phtml:

```
<div>   
    <span style="color:<?=($Good["color"]=="red")?"red":"black"?>;">
        <?=htmlspecialchars($Good["title"])?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
<?php
    foreach ($Goods as $Good)
        include ("template.phtml"); 
?>
```

Но в итоге получаем больше число inlcude, несколько сотен. Стал смотреть как их обойти и пришел к такому решению:

```
<?php
    $tmp    =   file_get_contents("template.phtml");
    foreach ($Goods as $Good)
        $Good["card"]   =   eval('?>'.$tmp);    
?>
```

Ну и далее там где мне нужно в шаблоне вывожу. Но на формах не однозначное отношение к eval. Подскажите как правильно сделать вывод этих карточек с точки зрения правильного подхода?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое, что стоит принять в работе с шаблонами - это то, что PHP-код, в данном случае заключенный в файл, шаблоном не является. PHP-код - это непосредственно код программы, и, несмотря на то, что с его помощью можно выводить разные там конструкции, делать это не нужно, в частности, по вышеописанным причинам.

Eval - действительно зло, по многим причинам, от полупараноидальной боязни, что в коде окажется что-то не то, до развращения конкретного разработчика как профессионала. Им действительно не стоит пользоваться, потому что это один большой красный флаг, на котором написано, что в архитектуре присутствуют фатальные ошибки.

Правильное решение при использовании шаблонов - это использование шаблонизаторов, явный лидер в текущий момент - это [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org). Шаблонизатор возьмет на себя всю головную боль по нахождению источников шаблонов (они не обязательно могут быть файлов), синтаксису, кэшированию и проблем скорострельности сбитых на скорую руку велосипедов. В общем, избавит от всей потецниальной головной боли, которая так и останется потенциальной, и, в самом комфортном случае, никогда не узнанной.

Чтобы добить, и, надеюсь, победить врожденную человеческую инетность по отношению к внедрению новых вещей, покажу, как это будет выглядить на твиге:

```
{# main.twig #}
...
   {% for product in products %}
       {% include 'product-card.twig' with { product: product } %}
   {% endfor %}
...
```

---

```
{# product-card.twig #}

<div>   
    <span style="color:{{ product.color|default('black') }}">
        {# да-да, преобразование в HTML entities происходит автоматом, пока не указано обратное #}
        {{ product.title }}
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, не стоит инклюдить постоянно шаблоны особенно в цикле,
достаточно :

```
 <div>
    <?php foreach($Goods as $Good):?>

        <span><?= $Good; ?></span>

    <? endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: В том то и дело, это карточка вставляется во многих местах и что бы ее изменить придется выискивать во всех страницах.

Answer (score 0):

В этом деле нет абсолютной истины, есть только мнения. Моё мнение такое: **в первую очередь разработчику должно быть удобно**. А сколько там инклудов это неважно.

Есть рутинные операции, специфические для *Представления*: экранирование тегов и кавычек, повторное подключение фрагментов или имитация наследования с перекрытием блоков. Если ваш шаблонизатор упрощает это, значит это годный шаблонизатор.

Шаблонизаторы со своим языком типа Smarty и Twig на выходе имеют тоже PHP-код, который инклудится. При всём уважении к мнению Etki, шаблон это *необязательно* другой язык, он вполне может быть "нативным" файлом php — как в [Plates](http://platesphp.com/) или [Symfony Templating](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/templating/introduction.html). Шаблоны [Blade](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) это php-файлы с некоторым синтаксическим сахаром.

eval() это зло, но пока он есть в языке, будут находиться его сторонники. Темы на SO:

- [When is eval evil in
  php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php)
- [When (if ever) is eval NOT
  evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499672/when-if-ever-is-eval-not-evil)

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что само по себе большое количество инклюдов - не проблема. При правильно настроенном кэшировании код скрипта будет находиться в памяти целиком, со всеми инклюдами.

Продолжим тем, что даже и без кэширования можно использовать `include_once()`, и фактиеская загрузка файла с диска будет произведена только единожды.

Ну и закончим тем, что будем называть вещи своими именами: код в вопросе - это не шаблон, а велосипед. Приведенный выше пример с twig-ом - далеко не единственная причина использовать этот *действительно* шаблонизатор.